# changing the language in the mailing address field into a local language

Tags: google-map, address, localization

I have enabled the Map and location settings in my organization to get the address searched. Is there a way to return the address in the local language(just for the address fields) on the detail page of account without changing the language of that user to the local language (while searching it shows in the local language but after saving it returns in the language specified on the user record)

Thanks in Advance